# Elasticsearch Get the values of a field - java API

Tags: java, json, api, elasticsearch, field

Hi guys i'm new to elasticsearch and im trying to process the error im currently getting here. So i just want a single field value for example "xmldata" which i added in a earlier process in the xml file. The xml is formatted to json an succesfully loaded to my ES-Server, the json file is correct.

Here my code:

```
        Client client = TransportClient.builder().build()
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

    // GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("store", "xml",
    // xsdid).setFields("xmldata").execute().actionGet();
    GetResponse response = client.prepareGet().setIndex("store").setType("xml").setId(xsdid).setFields("xml").execute().actionGet();

    String id = (String) response.getSource().get("xml");
```

i'm getting follow Error:

> MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Malformed content, found extra data after parsing: START_OBJECT];

My XML looks like this if you need it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><XmlDoc><FunctionResult result="success"><Message>Processed Correct!</Message></FunctionResult>
<billing>
<billing_id>571</billing_id>
<appid>mft</appid>
<senderbtid>20041900-107</senderbtid>
<receiverbtid>20041900-40</receiverbtid>
<messagetype>M_SLSRPT</messagetype>
<messageid>83815</messageid>
<messageprops/>
<tmid>842</tmid>
<tmmsgcnt>0</tmmsgcnt>
<tmmsgtotal>1</tmmsgtotal>
<procdate>2014-12-02T03:10:15.406</procdate>
<xmldata>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</xmldata></billing>
</XmlDoc>
```

Please help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

    GetResponse getResponse = client.prepareGet("database", "xsd", xsdid).execute().actionGet();

    Map<String, Object> source = getResponse.getSource();
```

Like this i'm getting the full json-file back

but is there a better way just to get the single one (xmldata)?